# jQuery .each() not running

Tags: jquery, html

For some reason this code doesn't seem to run. Is there a problem with it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.latitude').each(function(){
 var test = $(this).text();
 alert(test);
 });

});
```

I have these classes in the HTML:

```
<div class="latitude">40.5219444</div>
<div class="latitude">123</div>
<div class="latitude">892</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JZnaR/ - it works fine

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing wrong with the code you posted. The problem is elsewhere, or with some way it's integrated. When you say "doesn't seem to run", what do you mean? What's the error message?

Comment: no error message, but the alert doesn't show

Comment: Have you tried looking at an error console on your page to see if there a problem on your page?  Maybe you forgot to include jQuery or something like that?

Comment: @poerg, are you using Web Inspector or Firebug or something like that? I bet you are getting a javascript error.

Comment: Which browser? Do you use some other libs? prototype.js?

Comment: @poerg: check the JavaScript console for error messages; they might give you a clue about what's wrong. Your code is OK, so I'd wager you have some OTHER piece of Javascript that is executed before this, but contains an error that stops JavaScript execution before reaching this snippet.

Comment: @poerg: start from the very basic page that works and start adding your elements. Iteratively, one by one. When it breaks - you know what caused it.

Comment: @poerg: Can you post a complete html?

Comment: Are those divs created dynamically? can you do: alert($('.latitude').length);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your code doesn't run or your tags are out of reach, for example in an iFrame. I've excluded the possibility of an error, because you have mentioned in a comment that this is not the case.